# NetCDF to GeoTIFF

Tags: qgis, python, netcdf, climate

I downloaded a set of NetCDF files of [CMIP6 climate projections](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/projections-cmip6?tab=overview).

Here are the specifications of my NetCDF file:

```
dimensions(sizes): time(12), j(292), i(362), bnds(2), vertices(4)
variables(dimensions): float64 time(time), float64 time_bnds(time, bnds), int32 j(j), int32 i(i), float64 latitude(j, i), float64 longitude(j, i), float64 vertices_latitude(j, i, vertices), float64 vertices_longitude(j, i, vertices), float32 zos(time, j, i)
```

I would need to select a specific date of my NetCDF and then convert the selected object into a raster to be opened in QGIS.

How can I select a specific data of my NetCDF data and convert?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Just to make sure as you did not mention it in the text: You want to do it in PyQGIS Python?